# Flutter unable to load more item if screen is large when first fetch items

Tags: flutter

I currently want to implement an infinite scroll list. But when I first fetch, the items are not many so it doesn't cover the whole screen or make my SingleChildScrollView scrollable so it can't trigger the scroll listener to fetch more items. Is there anyway I can autofetch the item still it's scrollable?
Im using Provider to manage state

I want to make it automatically fetch still SingleChildScrollView scrollable.